# PHP Filter vs PHP htmlspecialchars vs sqli prepare

Tags: php, html, sql

I've been curious about the advantages/disadvantages of the mentioned methods of sql injection prevention.

The PHP filter just checks to see whether the input is of the correct format and returns true or false, which you can choose to send to the server or not.

PHP htmlspecialchars() function converts special charactors into string equivalents.

I'm not entirely sure on how sqli prepare works as I have limited knowledge of sql as of now, but am I correct in assuming it isn't necessary if you use either PHP filter functions and/or htmlspecialchars?

Just a note: If I have it all wrong, please keep the flaming constructive, I'm still learning PHP and SQL.

Comment: All three do totally different things, so it's not sensible or practical to compare them as methods of preventing SQL injection: but prepared statements are the best protection against SQL injection, while filters are for validation, and htmlspecialchars is purely related to presentation of html markup

Comment: Ahh I see, so I got it all wrong lol. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three things you mention are completely different, and only one has anything to do with SQL Injection.

- Filters, as you say, are for validating input; for instance, making sure that someone doesn't type a phone number into an email address field. They're not generally about security, just the data you require.
- `htmlspecialchars` escapes text *for use in HTML*, which makes sure people can't trick your site into outputting `<script>` tags, for instance. It's important to always escape data only for the context you're using it in, so you should never store HTML-escaped text in your database, and always escape it when you are actually outputting HTML.
- Prepared, parameterised, statements are an effective safeguard against SQL Injection. Instead of escaping each string to prevent it being run as SQL, the idea is to completely separate the query from the data, by sending the query to the database with placeholders where dynamic data will go. Since the DB knows that the values you pass to "fill in" the placeholders are data, an attacker cannot trick it into running extra SQL mixed in with the input.

Comment: I forgot to ask about mysqli_real_escape_string(). Considering much of sql syntax are just words such as insert and delete, I assume it isn't very effective compared to prepared statements?

Comment: Like htmlspecialchars, the idea there is to escape characters that would be interpreted specially, in this case inside a quoted string - so mostly it's about making sure a string with ' in it isn't interpreted as the end of the string. Used properly, it's pretty effective, although there are some edge cases with exotic character encodings, and it's easy to miss out a call to it in a long SQL string, as opposed to a strict policy of never writing SQL with anything other than placeholders.

Comment: Note that neither escaping nor preparing will prevent you from writing insecure code; it's up to you to make sure you're not using untrusted data in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

**htmlspecialchars();** convert special html symbols to special chars...

**filters** are used to validate the data

**prepared statements** helps protecting the sql injection as they used as parameters only

they are not appended to query